# Running sed command with Python doesn't work as it does in bash?

Tags: python-3.x, bash, sed, subprocess

I am attempting to execute this command from a Python script:

```
sed -i s/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/ ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
```

When I run from the bash console, it succeeds.

But when I run with the following code, it does not:

```
    process = subprocess.Popen(['sed', '-i', 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/', '~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.communicate()

    >>> sed: can't read ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences: No such file or directory
```

But this file clearly exists, I can find it, etc.

What's the issue? Am I missing something?

I'm on Python 3.9

Thanks!

Eduardo

Comment: Consider Barmar's comments about it being much sounder to edit JSON _as JSON_ instead of as text echoed.

Comment: In a past life I had a customer who insisted on doing things that way (parsing our API responses with their own hand-rolled parser) and it made my life miserable; we'd change libraries or settings and our output would be modified in a way that any standard-compliant parser would ignore, but theirs would blow up and they'd be calling support. Treating JSON _as JSON_ instead of treating it as strings is less trouble for everyone, including your future self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~` is expanded by the shell, it's not part of the actual pathname. Since you're not using the shell to execute the command, it's not expanded. You can use the Python function `os.path.expanduser()` to do this.

```
import os

process = subprocess.Popen(['sed', '-i', 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/', os.path.expanduser('~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences')], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I'm not sure why you're using `sed` to do this. Python can read and write the file itself. It also looks like you're trying to modify JSON using string operations. It would be better to use `json.load()` to read the file, modify the data, and then rewrite the file with `json.dump()`.

Comment: HA! I found the answer at the same time haha I'll leave as I did a bit differently but accept your answer, of course. Thank you!